# Nested loops altering rows in pandas - Avoiding "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

## Summary

I am trying to loop through a pandas dataframe, and to run a secondary loop at each iteration. The secondary loop calculates something that I want to append into the original dataframe, so that when the primary loop advances, some of the rows are recalculated based on the changed values. (For those interested, this is a simple advective model of carbon accumulation in soils. When a new layer of soil is deposited, mixing processes penetrate into older layers and transform their properties to a set depth. Thus, each layer deposited changes those below it incrementally, until a former layer lies below the mixing depth.)

I have produced an example of how I want this to work, however it is generating the common error message:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)
```

I have looked into the linked information in the error message as well as myriad posts on this forum, but none get into the continual looping through a changed dataframe.

## What I've tried, and some possible solutions

Below is some example code. This code works more or less as well as I want it to. But it produces the warning. Should I:

- Suppress the warning and continue working with this architecture? In this case, am I asking for trouble with un-reproducible results?
- Try a different architecture altogether, like a numpy array from the original dataframe?
- Try `df.append()` or `df.copy()` to avoid the warning?

I have tried `df.copy()' to no avail - the warning was still thrown.

## Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a':[x/2 for x in range(1,11)],
        'b':['hot dog', 'slider', 'watermelon', 'funnel cake', 'cotton candy', 'lemonade', 'fried oreo', 'ice cream', 'corn', 'sausage'], 
        'c':['meat', 'meat', 'vegan', 'vegan', 'vegan', 'vegan', 'dairy','dairy', 'vegan', 'meat']
}
)

print(a)

z = [x/(x+2) for x in range(1,5)]
print(z)

#Primary loop through rows of the main dataframe
for ind, row in a.iterrows():
    #Pull out a chunk of the dataframe. This is the portion of the dataframe that will be modified. What is below
    #this is already modified and locked into the geological record. What is above has not yet been deposited. 
    b = a.iloc[ind:(ind+len(z)), :]
    #Define the size of the secondary loop. Taking the minimum avoids the model mixing below the boundary layer (key error)
    loop = min([len(z), len(b)])
    #Now loop through the sub-dataframe and change accordingly.
    for fraction in range(loop):
        b['a'].iloc[fraction] = b['a'].iloc[fraction]*z[fraction]
    #Append the original dataframe with new data: 
    a.iloc[ind:(ind+loop), :] = b
    #Try df.copy(), but still throws warning!
    #a.iloc[ind:(ind+loop), :] = b.copy()

print(a)
```

Comment: You code produces no warning. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: You can suppress this warning by copying b explicitly (`b = a.iloc[ind:(ind+len(z)), :].copy()`) and by not assigning to a chained index in your second for loop (`b.loc[b.index[fraction], 'a'] = b['a'].iloc[fraction]*z[fraction]`). You should consider using pandas functions instead of nested loops in the future; this is not ideally written.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - I am using 3.9.7. That is good to hear that it produced no warnings when you ran it. What version are you using?

Comment: @CJR - You should see the last version! I am a recent convert from Matlab, and definitely not a coder. However, in this version I am trying to take advantage of .iloc instead of wrought indexing. In other words, I'm trying, but I am just not familiar enough with Pandas yet to do that. I am not aware of all of the capabilities when data are ordered, and most courses I've taken focus on using Pandas to access small parts of large data sets using masks and other filters. Maybe Pandas is not the right approach to my current problem?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes - Sorry - you asked about Pandas version, not Python. I am on Pandas 1.3.4. As far as I can tell, that is the most recent. There seems to be some uncertainty as to when this warning is thrown according to my reading on this site and others. Do you think it could simply be an instability that I can ignore?

Comment: Pandas is fine for what you're doing. The specific issue is that you're chaining a label lookup `b['a']` with a location lookup `.iloc[fraction]`. There are cases where that will force a copy (like if the integer lookup is non-contiguous), and then you're writing to a copy that isn't saved anywhere and will get garbage collected immediately. Usually the way you'd handle this problem is by calculating `a['z']` for the entire dataframe as you'd like and then just calling `a['a'] *= a['z']` once.

Comment: @CJR  the issue with that is that a['a'] should be changing each time a new a['a'].iloc[fraction]*z[fraction] is calculated. So even if I calculate the a['z'] for the entire dataframe (which is possible), your formulation misses the changes in a['a']. 
I have two questions about your solution above.

Comment: `(a * z_1) * z_2 * z_3` is the same as `a * (z_1 * z_2 * z_3)`. Just calculate the `(z_1 * z_2 * z_3)` part separately and then multiply it in. (You can also just make the changes noted in the first comment to fix the specific problem you have here)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239751/discussion-between-brosenheim-and-cjr).