# Deleting and adding numpy array rows in a for loop to create a dynamic subarray from larger numpy array,

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

## Summary of problem

### Ultimate goal

I would like to take a sub-array from a large input `numpy` array. This sub array is dynamic, and every iteration through the larger `numpy` input array will change the sub array so that I can perform a set of calculations that depend on previous iterations of the array. This involves nested for loops, which I realize is not very pythonic, but I don't know of another way.

### Problem

The problem arises when I add to the existing dynamic sub-array, it seems to grow extra bracketing. This seems simple to fix, but I am having trouble adapting my Matlab knowledge of array indexing to `numpy` indexing. I have not even started implementing my calculations yet, but I cannot seem to get the structure of this loop correct.

## What I've tried

I have [tried this originally in Pandas][1]. Originally, I thought I could write a pretty simply program to do this using pandas indexing and column naming. But it was SLOW! So I trying to streamline this by

1. changing the architecture and
2. relying on numpy instead of Pandas.

Below is a simple program that emulates what I want to do. I am sure I will have other questions, but this is the start. I have a simple (5, 2) array that I loop through the rows of. With each row after row 0, I add the new row to the top of the temp sub-array and delete the last row of the array, maintaining a (2, 2) array throughout. However, as you will see when you run this code, it results in some strange behavior that results in not being able to write the results into the output array. You will also see that I have tried several ways to add and delete columns. Whether these are optimal is besides the point - the current code is the closest I have gotten to running this program!

## Some Example code

This code 'works' in the sense that it doesn't trow errors. However, it doesnt' produce the desired results. In this case it would be an output array with the same values as the inputs (because I am not doing any calculations- this is just to get the architecture correct). The desired result would be that each loop creates a sub array in this order:

```
n=1 [1 1]
n=2 [[1,1], [2,2]]
n=3 [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
n=4 [[3, 3], [4, 4]]
... 
N   [[N-1, N-1], [N, N]].
```

This does not need to be limited to 2 items (if list) or rows (if array), and the length will be set by an input variable. Thus, the size of this array must be dynamic (set during the call of the function). Furthermore, I supply a simple example here, but each loop will basically need to add a row from the input. It will be a little more advanced than simply a 2 member NDarray. Lists have the advantage of being able to use .append and .pop attributes, but as far as I can tell, arrays do not. I present the following code example using only arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4,4], [5,5]])
print('Original a array: ', a)
out = np.empty_like(a)
b = np.empty(len(a[0,:]))
for ii, rr in enumerate(a):
    if ii == 0:
        c = [a[ii]]
    else:
        print('Before: ', c)
        #Add next row from array a to the temp array for calculations
        c =  np.insert(c, 1, [rr], axis=0)
        print('During: ', c)
        #Remove the last row of the temp array prior to calculations
        #indices_to_remove = [0]
        #d = c[~np.isin(np.arange(c.size), [indices_to_remove])]
        d = c[1::]
        c = [d]
        print('After: ', c)

        #Add the temp array to the output array after calculations
        #THIS THROWS ERRORS, AND I THINK IT IS DUE TO THE INCREASING NUMBERS OF BRACKETS.
        #out[ii, :] = c
    
    
        
    #print(c)


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186681/nested-loops-altering-rows-in-pandas-avoiding-a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on?noredirect=1#comment124076103_70186681
```

Comment: There's no such a thg as 'dynamic array'.  What MATLAB matrix or action is 'dynamic'?

Comment: Think in terms of array dimensions, the `shape`, not in terms 'number of brackets'.  In MATLAB this is the `size`.  What's the purpose of putting `a[ii]` in a list, `[a[ii]]`?  Or `[d]`?  Don't use `[]` randomly!

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is 1-base indexing whereas Python uses 0-base indexing.
let's say we have a 2D array like this:

```
   a=  [[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]]
```

In MATLAB if you do `a(1, 1)` you will get `1` in python `a[1, 1]` you will get 4. Also as you know in MATLAB you can do natural indexing which works if you do `a(6) = 6` in python if you do that you will get `IndexError:` . it is almost the same, except in python it starts from 0.

Here is the working example with your desired results.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4,4], [5,5]])
test = []
for idx in range(len(a)):
    if idx == 0:
        test.append(a[idx])
    test.append(a[idx:idx+2, :])
# remove the last [5, 5]
test.pop(-1)
for i in test:
    print(i, end=',\n')
```

output

```
[1 1],
[[1 1]
 [2 2]],
[[2 2]
 [3 3]],
[[3 3]
 [4 4]],
[[4 4]
 [5 5]],
```

Comment: This is close to what I was after, but it is flawed because you are making a list that is continually growing. For this problem, I would need that list (or array) to grow up to a certain size, then maintain that size while adding a new item and deleting the oldest item for each iteration. I believe this was unclear in my syntax above, and I have edited it. The output should be: 
```
n=0     [1 1]
n=1     [[1 1], [2 2]]
n=2     [[2 2], [3 3]]
n=3     [[3 3], [4 4]]
...
N        [[N-1 N-1], [N N]]
```
The length of the list (or array) needs to be flexible.